# How do i assign a function to be running in a specific column

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm developing a Google Sheet spreadsheet to save time at my work routine and I end it up bumping into the script world. This is a very new tool to me and naturally I've been struggling to make it happen.

Currently I'm using Google App script.

I have this function right here:

```
function insertFollowerCount() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(this.sheetName);
var previousData = prevData();
var followers = getFollowers();

sheet.appendRow([Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'") , followers, followers-previousData.followers]);
 };

function getFollowers() {
return parseInt(fetch(instagram_base_url + followers)['data']['user']['edge_followed_by']['count']);
 }

var header = {'Cookie': ********}

 function fetch(url) {
 var ignoreError = {
"muteHttpExceptions": true,
"validateHttpsCertificates":false,
"headers":header
 };

 var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, ignoreError).getContentText();
 var data = JSON.parse(source);
 return data;
 }

 function prevData() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(this.sheetName);
 var Avals = sheet.getRange("B1:B").getValues();
 var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
 var prevFollowers = sheet.getRange("B"+Alast).getValues();
 var prevEngagement = sheet.getRange("H"+Alast).getValues();
 return {
 followers: parseInt(prevFollowers),
 engagement: prevEngagement    
 }

 };
```

The code that i have take my instagram info and turns into data at my Google sheets. What im looking for is to programing this data to be running at my column 'H' and so on at my Google Sheets every time i run the script

Comment: "a spreadsheet" is a bit vague. Are you talking about Google Sheets? Apple Numbers? Something else?

Comment: What do you mean by "running on my columm 'H'"? That code looks like it is trying to make an HTTP request to an external URL. It doesn't touch your spreadsheet.

Comment: There's an **edit** link by your question. Don't fill the comments with masses of unreadable code.

Comment: Thank you for point it out, i just edited.